# Javascript reference nested object elements from another module

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Simple question, but it doesn't seem to be working how I expect...
I'm trying to access the value from a nested object, however I'm getting that (for this example) 'person' is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Example:

config.settings.js:

```
var configs = {
    person: {
        'name': 'John',
        'number': 27,
        'color': blue
    },
    place: {
        'town': 'springville',
        'population': 201827
    }
}
module.exports = configs;
```

main.js:

```
var configSettings = require('config.settings');
module.exports = {
    run: function(){
        console.log(configSettings[person][name]);
   }
}
```

Comment: `configSettings.person.name`

Comment: 'Cannot read property "name" of undefined'

Comment: That means your `require()` failed.

Comment: Ended up using `configSettings.person['name']`

without putting the ' around the inner most keys I kept getting type errors.

Comment: That means exactly, *exactly*, the same thing as `configSettings.person.name`

Comment: I understand- for some reason kept throwing type errors until the nested objects (person, place, in this example) were made strings with " around them like "person", "place". However in my real project the nested object names are numbers (0, 1, 2...) so what I don't understand is why making them strings ("0:", "1:", "2:"...etc) changed from "undefined" error/type error to working. Reading around SO somebody said the nested object keys need to have a type but this I do not understand.

Comment: Well in future, it would help people help you if you posted the *real* code, instead of code that is *not* the real code. When a property name looks like what a variable name can look like, you can use `object.propertyName`. When it's a number (which *cannot* be a variable name), then you do indeed have to use the `[ ]` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dot *accessor* such as

```
configSettings.person.name
```

And make sure your are properly importing your config.

Comment: 'Cannot read property "name" of undefined'

Comment: Well I don't know what's going on with it- imported just as shown here

Answer (score 0):

First make sure blue is defined otherwise is a typo and should be a string

```
person: {
        'name': 'John',
        'number': 27,
        'color': "blue"
    },
```

and I sugest use dot notation

```
configSettings.person.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Had to make the inner keys strings and reference with `configSettings.person['name']`

Also I had to make the inner keys into strings- e.g. "person:", "place":

I'm just reporting what fixed it for me- I do not understand what the original problem was as of yet, without making the inner keys into strings I was getting type errors when trying to access.

Comment: This does not show what the problem was.